# Deletion complexity of last element in double linked list

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity, doubly-linked-list, discrete-mathematics

[image]

If you want to delete **Node A** then you have to traverse only one and complexity will **O(1)**

If you want to delete **Node C** then you have to traverse two times and complexity will **O(n)**

If you want to delete **Node D** then you have to traverse three times and complexity might be **O(n)**
However, the deletion complexity of the last node in a double linked list is **O(1)**

I don't get this point how it works?

I checked this link but I did not get/ did not understand my answer
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19237866/why-is-removing-a-node-from-a-doubly-linked-list-faster-than-removing-a-node-fro)

Comment: Big-O complexity only kicks in when you're talking about inputs that can be arbitrarily large. Are you asking specifically about this diagram? Or about things with this general shape? (By the way, that's my answer you've linked. Happy to clarify things.)

Comment: I want to an explanation about last node deletion complexity.
Plz, explain Both given image case and a large data set case.

Comment: from the diagram you do not seem to have access to tail pointer which means the deletion of Node D shoud be O(n)

Comment: @ Barış Akkurt  so if there is mentioned a tail pointer then it would be O(1) complexity. ?(in case of last node deletion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complexity isn't in removing the item, but *locating* it.

In a doubly-linked list, you typically have a pointer to the last element in the list so that you can append. So if somebody asks you to delete the last element, you can just remove it.

If somebody asks you to delete the k<sup>th</sup> element of the list, you have to start at the beginning and traverse k links to find the element before you can delete it. That's going to be O(k), which in the worst case would be O(n-1).

Answer (score 0):

Only case when deletion of last node from doubly linked list will be O(1) complexity is when you have direct access to this node , something like tail pointer. Otherwise you will have to traverse whole list which takes O(n).