# deleting from doubly linked list - java

Tags: java, nodes, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to better undserstand my teachers notes on how to delete a node from a doubly linked list, what she had on the boards is

```
 public void deleteNode(Node D){
 Node current = head;
 while(current.data != D.data && current.next != null){
  current = current.next;
   }
  d.prev.next = d.next;
  d.next.prev = current.prev.
 }
```

I can't help but feel like this isn't enough to remove a node.  I was thinking maybe she meant

```
current.prev.next = d.next and
current.next.prev = d.prev
```

Once I figure out how to understand this better would it make sense if I wanted to delete a node from the middle by doing

```
public void deleteMiddle(){
    Node current = head;
    int i = 0;
    while(i < size/2){
        current = current.next;
        i++;
    }
    deleteNode(current);
}
```

Comment: The deletion of node from a doubly-linked list can be done in [O(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895769/time-complexity-of-node-deletion-in-singly-and-doubly-linked-lists).  There is no need to iterate at all.  This is one of the huge advantages of a doubly-linked list over a singly linked list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way would be to either pass in the value, i.e. the `data`, or to make the method private, to protect against misuse.

Or do both:

```
public void deleteNode(int data) {
    Node current = head;
    while (current != null && current.data != data) {
        current = current.next;
    }
    deleteNode(current);
    // Note: We silently do nothing if 'data' not found
}
private void deleteNode(Node node) {
    if (node != null) {
        // Here we can rely on 'node' actually being in our list
        if (node.prev != null)
            node.prev.next = node.next;
        else
            head = node.next;
        if (node.next != null)
            node.next.prev = node.prev;
        else
            tail = node.prev;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to point out for the OP that Andreas's first function takes a *value* iterates through the list to find the node, and deletes the node.  The second function takes a *node* and simply deletes it without iterating.  Thus the complexity of the first function is O(N) and the complexity of the second is O(1).

Comment: However, I do not necessarily agree with his assertion that the "correct" way is to make the function private.  I would say it depends on use case.

Comment: Awesome thanks you!  I don't know why I have a hard time visualizing the Linked list structures, it seems like the only data structure I struggle with but this cleared it up thank you

Comment: @Andreas    but so to target my last question, if I wanted to just delete the middle node( got this question wrong on my test haven't had time to see her since) would I do something similar to what I did in the original posting?

Comment: @MFisherKDX so you're saying it would me more concise to use the second function if I knew EXACTLY which node i wanted to delete, and the first function is more for if I only knew the value of the node?

Comment: @alwaysquestioning Your `deleteMiddle` method works as-is, calling the second method above. The reason I stated that the `deleteNode(Node node)` should be `private` to be "correct", is that you should guard the internals of your class against corruption. What would happen if you called the method with a `Node` from another list? You might update nodes of the other list, but update `head` and `tail` of this list, totally corrupting both this and the other list. That why a method like that should only be callable by *trusted* code, in this case other methods of the class.